# SQL Server conversion issue with datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, casting, sql-server-2008-r2

I always use this code for conversion in datetime:

```
 DECLARE @a datetime
 SET @a= CONVERT(datetime,'2012-12-28 14:04:43') 
 print @a
```

But this does not work anymore! I tried even restarting SQL Server, but the problem remains:

[image: Conversion error]

The error in the image is in Italian. In English should be:

> *The conversion of a char data type to datetime resulted in a datetime
>   value that is out of range of allowed values​​.*

Comment: Have you recently changed the default language of your login to Italian? This affects `DATEFORMAT` and how dates are parsed. If you do `SET LANGUAGE english` your code works fine but fails under `SET LANGUAGE italian`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are many formats supported by SQL Server - see the [MSDN Books Online on CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). Most of those formats are **dependant** on what settings you have - therefore, these settings might work some times - and sometimes not.

The way to solve this is to use the (slightly adapted) **ISO-8601 date format** that is supported by SQL Server - this format works **always** - regardless of your SQL Server language and dateformat settings.

The [ISO-8601 format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx) is supported by SQL Server comes in two flavors:

- `YYYYMMDD` for just dates (no time portion); note here: **no dashes!**, that's very important! `YYYY-MM-DD` is **NOT** independent of the dateformat settings in your SQL Server and will **NOT** work in all situations!

or:

- `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` for dates and times - note here: this format *has* dashes (but they *can* be omitted), and a fixed `T` as delimiter between the date and time portion of your `DATETIME`.

This is valid for SQL Server 2000 and newer.

If you use SQL Server 2008 or newer and the `DATE` datatype (only `DATE` - **not** `DATETIME`!), then you can indeed also use the `YYYY-MM-DD` format and that will work, too, with any settings in your SQL Server.

Don't ask me why this whole topic is so tricky and somewhat confusing - that's just the way it is. But with the `YYYYMMDD` format, you should be fine for any version of SQL Server and for any language and dateformat setting in your SQL Server.

So in your concrete case - use this:

```
DECLARE @a datetime
SET @a= CONVERT(datetime, '2012-12-28T14:04:43') 
print @a
```

and this should work on **any** SQL Server installation, with **any** language and date format settings.

If you run your original code for US English - it will work just fine:

```
SET LANGUAGE English

DECLARE @a datetime
SET @a= CONVERT(datetime, '2012-12-28 14:04:43') 
print @a

Dec 28 2012  2:04PM
```

but if you use Italian (or German, or British, or French) as your language, it will fail **because** the format **without** the `T` in the middle of the date/time string is **NOT** language-independent and not "safe" :

```
SET LANGUAGE Italian

DECLARE @a datetime
SET @a= CONVERT(datetime, '2012-12-28 14:04:43') 
print @a
```

> *Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 4
>
>   La conversione di un tipo di dati varchar in datetime ha generato un valore non compreso nell'intervallo dei valori consentiti.*

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to convert a string to a datetime. Problem is with the date part. Best way is to get the date string into `ISO format (yyyymmdd)` and then convert. Try this;

```
DECLARE @a datetime
SET @a= CONVERT(datetime,replace('2012-12-28 14:04:43', '-','')) 
print @a
```

Comment: Thank you! this works. But I don't know why my code works on my friend's pc.

Comment: It could be his local culture settings.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the default date time format changed on your computer.  Add the conversion specification back in:

```
SET @a= CONVERT(datetime,'2012-12-28 14:04:43', 121)
```